# Loop does not delete all needed views from RelativeLayout

Tags: android, textview

I need to find all TextView inside a RelativeLayout, for this, I'm using for(;;) loop, but face with the strange problem, the loop doesn't delete all Views. If a layout has 2 child's, 1 will be deleted and 1 will stay. Sometimes, loop deletes all TextView's but on the next use leave 1 anyway.

Here is my code:

```
            int viewCount = relativeLayout.getChildCount();

            for (int i1=0; i1 < viewCount ; i1++){
                if (relativeLayout.getChildAt(i1) instanceof TextView) {
                    relativeLayout.removeViewAt(i1);
                }
            }
```

**EDIT:**

Here is the right loop:

```
while (viewCount != -1){
                if (relativeLayout.getChildAt(viewCount) instanceof TextView) {
                    relativeLayout.removeViewAt(viewCount);
                }
                viewCount--;
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the the RelativeLayout's list of children shrinks as you remove Views, and you aren't taking that into account.

Let's say my RelativeLayout has two children, and I am using your for loop to remove them.

1. In the first iteration, I remove the first child (at index 0).
2. My RelativeLayout now has one child. The second child is now at index 1, since the list of children is a list of length 1.
3. The loop iterates to index 1
4. I call `relativeLayout.getChildAt(1)`, which is null because the only child is at position 0. The second child is never removed.

There are a variety of solutions to this problem. One common one is to iterate backwards through the list of children so that you are always only removing the last item.